# Datejs how to switch language?

Tags: web-applications, switch-statement, datejs

I am building a web app for iOS Android and just included the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) library.

The Datejs library comes with 150 languages support

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-en-US.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-de-DE.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="date-fr-FR.js"></script>
```

and so on..

Should the user change language, how can I switch from US to FR for example, within my App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you must pick a single file.  You can't load them all.  You might try a module loader like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), but I don't think date.js will cooperate well since it modifies the global `Date` object.  Also, it was written a long time ago and [has since been abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).  If you're going to continue using it, I suggest you use [Gregory's fork](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/).

As an alternative, I suggest you consider [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) or [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates).  Both will handle the requirement of being able to switch languages on the fly.  Moment is more comprehensive and more popular, but Sugar has some of the natural language parsing that DateJS was aiming for.  Either would be a much more stable and supportable choice than date.js.

Comment: started with sugar, and all working at first try. The whole page of editable examples is just great!!!

Comment: replaced previous datejs code with sugar code and all working at first try. The whole page of editable examples is just great to try different combinations !!!

Fierce!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Be sure to say thanks to [Andrew Plummer](https://twitter.com/l_andrew_l) and [the Sugar team](https://twitter.com/sugarjs1).

Answer (score 0):

In my updated fork (https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs) you can switch using AJAX or if you use NodeJS it's all dynamic.

In the updated version it's a simple call to the method `Date.i18n.setLanguage` with the correct IETF code (e.g. 'es-MX').